# update some values of pandas dataframe based on dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['a','b','c'],'y':[1,2,3],'z':[4,5,6],'o':[100,200,300]})
df.set_index('x',inplace=True)
```

I'd like to update the values of indices `a` and `c` with the following dictionary:

```
d = {'a':{'y':6,'z':8}, 'c':{'y':9}}
```

Based on similar questions I tried the `map` and `replace` methods, but could not get the desired output:

```
   y  z    o
x           
a  6  8  100
b  2  5  200
c  9  6  300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `update`

```
df.update(pd.DataFrame(d).T)
df
Out[132]: 
     y    z    o
x               
a  6.0  8.0  100
b  2.0  5.0  200
c  9.0  6.0  300
```